# Checking of two key values present in two separate arrays inside an associative dynamically

Tags: php, associative-array

I am new to PHP programming; I am facing a issue in array operations. My array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [c7cbe719-909a-480d-85b4-51ac545505dc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lot_id] => 2
                    [lot_qty] => 5
                    [reference_id] => 2
                    [operation_id] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [lot_id] => 2
                    [lot_qty] => 2
                    [reference_id] => 2
                    [operation_id] => 4273
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to compare the value of 'lot_id' of Array index 0 with that of 'lot_id' of Array index 1 or operation_id value of the first array with that of second array

I have tried to traverse the array in this manner:

```
foreach( $products_uuid_array as $k => $v) {

            foreach($v as $index => $value) {

                if( $products_uuid_array[$k][$index]['lot_id']) {

                }
                
            }
        }
```

The $products_uuid_array is the associative array which I have defined above. After this I could not proceed as to how access both the keys simultaneously and compare between them. Kindly suggest if possible where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it something like that, current index + 1 to get the next index, and check if exist, if exist u now have current and next, and u can compare them.

```
foreach( $products_uuid_array as $k => $v) {
            foreach($v as $index => $value) {
                $next = $index + 1 ; // current key + 1
                if(isset($products_uuid_array[$k][$next])){ // check if exist
                    echo  "currentIndex: ".$products_uuid_array[$k][$index]['lot_id']." // next index: ". $products_uuid_array[$k][$next]['lot_id'];
                }

            }
        }
```

also in the second foreach you can replace

```
 $products_uuid_array[$k][$index]['lot_id'] 
 $products_uuid_array[$k][$next]['lot_id']
```

with

```
$v[$index]['lot_id']
$v[$next]['lot_id']
```

for better code readability, just give it a proper name inside the foreach

Comment: Thanks for replying; I am trying this approach. Another question if the number of arrays is not known beforehand that is here you have considered $next = $index +1 ; If the $index is not known from beforehand (Ex.- there are 4 arrays) then will we have to iterate over the index and then set the next value? @benkov

Comment: if you have 4 arrays, you still want to compare it with the first value ? or to compare the current iteration value with the next ?